# Finitely generated module with a submodule that's not finitely

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am going to Find Finitely generated module with a submodule that's not finitely generated.please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any non-Noetherian ring as a module over itself.

Comment: Your point being that every non-Noetherian ring has [an ideal that is not finitely generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring#Characterizations).